# Deny connections from IPv6 (Debian Buster)

Tags: iptables, firewall, ipv6, fail2ban, ufw

Inexplicably, it seems like there has been a bug for a long time in one of the most widely used firewalls, UFW, which does not allow for adding IPv6 deny rules above any other IPv4 rules.

The result is that in order to deny IPv6 addresses one has to rewrite the entire ruleset after adding an IPv6 deny rule, because the IPv4 rules (on top) override the newly added deny rules on IPv6 addresses.

Fail2ban also seems littered with errors for applying IPv6 deny rules. What are some workarounds people are using for this?

Comment: Use a more modern Linux distribution? And probably not ufw. I threw out ufw years ago and run firewalld, even on Debian/Ubuntu systems. It's slightly more complicated, but it actually works.

Comment: Nice, will check out firewalld! Thanks. Is Debian connected with a higher rate of security breaches within Linux? What's an alternative that's more secure than Debian stable for a web server?

Comment: I personally run all my web sites on CentOS (or RHEL) in part to take advantage of SELinux.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you. I think I'd rather remain a pirate than join the Navy though ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching the way to disable all ipv6 then easy way to switch them of on kernel level.

> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

> net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1

Add this lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot or `sudo sysctl -p` to apply new settings

Comment: Thanks. Is this a common workaround for a web server running WordPress? What is the upside of having IPv6 enabled?

Comment: I don't think this works, I disabled through those lines and, after rebooting, my WordPress firewall still flagged attacks from IPv6

Comment: It works and compliantly disable ipv6 on the server. Check all incoming connections first with something like `sudo lsof -i` or `inet6` line from `ifconfig` output. Maybe you have some other problem with wordpress

Comment: I don't see any IPv6 in either of those outputs. What I'm seeing is output like this on my WordPress firewall log, where the SOURCE IP field comes after "CRITICAL" --

03/Aug/20 18:57:46  #3007444  CRITICAL     2  2a01:4f8:c0c:61cc::1  GET /index.php - ASCII character 0x00 (NULL byte) - [SERVER:HTTP_REFERER = f%00bar]

Comment: Did you clean your logs after apply this?

Comment: Yes. I rebooted the server and I ran the security stress-testing app from NinjaFirewall's website.